# Syntax Error (Invalid syntax) Using Python

Tags: python

I keep getting a syntax error and have not been able to fix it after looking at countless sites. I'm thinking I must be missing something. I've written code previously and everything has worked except for this. I've attached some of my code below and the error message underneath it. I'm still new at coding, so it might not be that clear. If anyone could help me that would be great!

Partial code:

```
d = dict(0 == 0, I don == 1, "Unknown" == 2, "Unsure" == 3, "Hacking" == 4, "Anonymity" == 5, "Privacy" == 6, "Addiction" == 7, "Catfishing" == 8, "Loss of interest in the real world" == 9,"Headaches" == 10,"Mental health" == 11,"Heart attack" == 12,"Financial collapse" == 13,"Anonymity & online harrassment" == 14,"Dissociation" == 15,"Personal data and privacy terms" == 6,"Addiction and neglecting the real world" == 16,"Scamming" == 17,"Reduce real-life interaction" == 18,"Legal issues" == 19,"Digital property can be damaged more easily" == 20,"I don't use metaverse" == 21,"Program error" == 22,"Scams and sextings" == 23,"Escapicism" == 24,"Mental risks" == 11,"Identity fraud" == 25,"Scammers and sexual predators" == 23,"Scams and catfishing" == 26,"Meeting someone when in reality it's someone else behind a screen" == 8,"Private manners" == 27,"Fraud" == 17,"Cyber bullying" == 28,"Bad advertisement content" == 29,"Wrong knowledgement" == 30,"Reality confusion" == 31,"Security risks & finanical risks" == 32,"Sexual harrassment" == 33,"lag issues" == 34,"Data collection without consent, Addiction" == 35,"Identity theft" == 36,"Wrong investment" == 13,"GDPR" == 37,"Addiction and health probelems" == 38,"Infringement of personal information" == 39,"Crime and anonymity" == 5,"Invasion of privacy" == 6,"Privacy and hacking" == 40,"Crime" == 41,"Unable to distinguish between reality and virtuality" == 31,"Leak of private informations" == 39,"Privacy and security risks that come with technology" == 42,"Losing touch with reality" == 15,"People using it to bully/harrass others" == 43,
                    "Sex crimes and theft" == 41,
                    "Deterioration of face to face communication" == 66)
```

Error message:

```
 Input In [20]
    d = dict(0 == 0, I don == 1, "Unknown" == 2, "Unsure" == 3, "Hacking" == 4, "Anonymity" == 5, "Privacy" == 6, "Addiction" == 7, "Catfishing" == 8, "Loss of interest in the real world" == 9,"Headaches" == 10,"Mental health" == 11,"Heart attack" == 12,"Financial collapse" == 13,"Anonymity & online harrassment" == 14,"Dissociation" == 15,"Personal data and privacy terms" == 6,"Addiction and neglecting the real world" == 16,"Scamming" == 17,"Reduce real-life interaction" == 18,"Legal issues" == 19,"Digital property can be damaged more easily" == 20,"I don't use metaverse" == 21,"Program error" == 22,"Scams and sextings" == 23,"Escapicism" == 24,"Mental risks" == 11,"Identity fraud" == 25,"Scammers and sexual predators" == 23,"Scams and catfishing" == 26,"Meeting someone when in reality it's someone else behind a screen" == 8,"Private manners" == 27,"Fraud" == 17,"Cyber bullying" == 28,"Bad advertisement content" == 29,"Wrong knowledgement" == 30,"Reality confusion" == 31,"Security risks & finanical risks" == 32,"Sexual harrassment" == 33,"lag issues" == 34,"Data collection without consent, Addiction" == 35,"Identity theft" == 36,"Wrong investment" == 13,"GDPR" == 37,"Addiction and health probelems" == 38,"Infringement of personal information" == 39,"Crime and anonymity" == 5,"Invasion of privacy" == 6,"Privacy and hacking" == 40,"Crime" == 41,"Unable to distinguish between reality and virtuality" == 31,"Leak of private informations" == 39,"Privacy and security risks that come with technology" == 42,"Losing touch with reality" == 15,"People using it to bully/harrass others" == 43,
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You need quotes around that string, just like you have quotes around all the other strings.

Comment: When you were "looking at countless sites" did you at any point search for "how to create a dictionary"?  E.g.: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/create-a-dictionary-in-python-python-dict-methods/

Answer (score 2):

There are two things wrong with this code:

1. One of your strings doesn't have quotes around it (that's the `SyntaxError` you hit)
2. You're passing a series of bool arguments, e.g. `"Unsure" == 3` which will always evaluate to `False`, to the `dict()` constructor (that's the `TypeError` you'd hit once you fixed the `SyntaxError`).

It's easier to specify a dict as a literal than to use the `dict()` constructor.  Do:

```
d = {
    0: 0,
    "I don": 1,
    "Unknown": 2,
    "Unsure": 3,
    "Hacking": 4,
    "Anonymity": 5,
    # etc
}
```